# Question based on compound Interest

Tags: arithmetic

A certain amount is invested in scheme A for 6 years which offers simple interest at the rate of x% per annum. The same amount is invested in scheme B for 2 years which offers compound interest compounded annually at the rate of 10% per annum. Interest earned from scheme A is twice of that earned in scheme B. If the rate of interest of scheme A had been (x+2)% per annum, the difference between the interests after corresponding periods would have been $3960. What is the amount invested in each scheme?

Problem: I am getting the answer to be 12000. While the book says the answer is 33000

---

My Attempt:

$$\frac{P*x*6}{100}=\frac{P*21}{100}*2$$

$$x=7$$
ATQ:
$$\frac{54P}{100}-\frac{21P}{100}=3960$$

$$P=12000$$

Comment: The difference in interest rate is in Scheme A and not Scheme B. You have mistakenly assumed the change for Scheme B I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the interest in Scheme A had been $x \%$, then it would have been $ \$3960$ less than what the interest would have been if rate was $(x+2)\%$.

So, your equation must be $$\frac{54 \rm P}{100 }-\frac{42 \rm  P}{100}=3960 \implies \rm P=33,000$$

Comment: The difference in SI earned in Scheme A at 9% p.a and SI earned in scheme A at 7% is what they have asked for?

Comment: @Soumee Yes, exactly.

Comment: Ok ok...Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2673441/394202

Answer (score 1):

It says "after corresponding periods", which implies the interest of scheme B for $2$ years is:
$$\frac{P*21}{100}*2.$$