# Mathematics (Partial Differentiation) arising in an Electronics engineering question

Tags: partial-derivative

We have the following equations:

$$V_T=I_BR_T+V_{BE}+(I_B+I_C) R_E \tag1$$

$$=>I_B=\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{R_T+R_E} \tag2$$

$$I_C=\beta I_B+(1+\beta)I_{CO} \tag3$$

Substituting $I_B$ from 2nd eq to 3rd eq yields:

$$I_C=\beta\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{R_T+R_E}+(1+ \beta)I_{CO} \tag4$$

$$I_C(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})=\frac{\beta(V_T-V_{BE})}{R_T+R_E}+(1+\beta)I_{CO} \tag {4a}$$

Also given that:

$$S=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial I_{CO}}=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E}} \tag5$$

$$S'=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial V_{BE}}=-\frac{\beta}{(1+\beta)R_E+R_T} \tag6$$

How can I differentiate $I_C$ w.r.t $\beta$ to obtain

$$S''=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial\beta}=\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}[I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)+\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}+SI_{CO} \tag7
]$$

provided $I_{CO}$ and $V_{BE}$ are constant?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $$I_C(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})=\frac{\beta(V_T-V_{BE})}{R_T+R_E}+(1+\beta)I_{CO} \tag {4a}$$ as
$$I_C(1+a{\beta})=b \beta+(1+\beta)I_{CO}\implies I_C=\frac{b \beta+(1+\beta)I_{CO} }{1+a{\beta} } $$ and go on.

Comment: I have done as you said. But I am not able to accommodate S in the equation.

$$S''=\frac{(1+a\beta )(b+I_{CO})-(b\beta+(1+\beta)I_{CO}.a}{(1+a\beta )^2}$$

$$=\frac{b+I_{CO}+ab\beta +a\beta I_{CO}-ab\beta-aI_{CO}-a\beta I_{CO}}{(1+a\beta )^2}$$

Comment: $$=\frac{b+I_{CO}(1-a)}{(1+a\beta )^2}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{V_T-V_{BE}}{R_T+R_E}+I_{CO}(1-\frac{R_E}{R_T+R_E})}{(1+\frac{R_E\beta}{R_T+R_E})^2}$$