# Mathematical calculations arising in Physics

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone please tell how can I use the following two equations:

$$S=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E}} \tag5$$

and

$$S''=\frac{\frac{V_T-V_{BE}}{R_T+R_E}+I_{CO}(1-\frac{R_E}{R_T+R_E})}{(1+\frac{R_E\beta}{R_T+R_E})^2}$$

to arrive at:

$$S''=\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}[I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)+\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}+SI_{CO} \tag7
]$$
?

Comment: surely you also need to tell us what $I_C$ is: this does not appear in your first two equations

Comment: @rbird https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673441/mathematics-partial-differentiation-arising-in-an-electronics-engineering-ques/2673458#2673458

Comment: is $S''$ a product of $\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}$ and $I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)+\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}+SI_{CO}$, or the brackets imply a different operation?

Comment: @JohnGlenn It denotes the product.

Comment: Is $S''$ correct? Because based on the values of $S$, $I_C$ and $I_B$, what I get is: $$S''=\frac1{\beta(1+\beta)}S(I_C-I_{CO})$$

Comment: I'll post my computation, tell me if there are any mistakes in the definitions and in the arithmetic

Comment: @JohnGlenn There might be an error in the sign before $\beta S R_E$ in the final expression. I actually posted this as an electronics engg. question. I am attaching the link for your reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/316246/115973

Comment: Okay, I am posting my answer soon, please evaluate my computation afterwards

Comment: @Soumee do the calculations hold?

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$

> Let:
>   $$a=\frac{R_E}{R_T+R_E}$$
>   Given:
>   $$S=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E}}$$
>   $$S=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\beta a}; 1+\beta a=\frac{1+\beta}S $$
>   From (2) and (3):
>   $$I_B=\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{R_T+R_E} \tag2$$
>   $$\frac{V_T-V_{BE}}{R_T+R_E}=I_B+I_Ca$$
>   $$I_C=\beta I_B+(1+\beta)I_{CO} \tag3$$
>   $$ I_B=\frac{I_C-(1+\beta)I_{CO}}\beta$$

Then:
$$S''=\frac{\frac{V_T-V_{BE}}{R_T+R_E}+I_{CO}(1-\frac{R_E}{R_T+R_E})}{(1+\frac{R_E\beta}{R_T+R_E})^2}$$
$$S''=\frac{I_B+I_C+I_{CO}(1-a)}{(1+\beta a)^2}$$
$$S''=\Biggl(\frac{S}{1+\beta}\Biggr)^2(I_B+I_Ca+I_{CO}(1-a))$$
$$S''=\Biggl(\frac{S}{1+\beta}\Biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{I_C-(1+\beta)I_{CO}}{\beta}+I_Ca+I_{CO}-I_{CO}a\Biggr)$$

> Kindly check this because the equation above *neatly* equals to:
>   $$S''=\Biggl(\frac{S}{1+\beta}\Biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{I_C-(1+\beta)I_{CO}+(I_C -I_{CO})a\beta+I_{CO}\beta}\beta\Biggr)$$
>   $$S''=\Biggl(\frac{S}{1+\beta}\Biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{I_C-I_{CO}-I_{CO}\beta+I_Ca\beta -I_{CO}a\beta+I_{CO}\beta}\beta\Biggr)$$
>   $$S''=\Biggl(\frac{S}{1+\beta}\Biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{I_C(1+a\beta)-I_{CO}(1+\cancel{\beta}+a\beta-\cancel{\beta)}}\beta\Biggr)$$
>
> > $$S''=\Biggl(\frac{S}{1+\beta}\Biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{(I_C-I_{CO})(1+\beta a)}{\beta}\Biggr)$$

Resulting to:
$$S''=\frac{S^2(I_C-I_{CO})(1+\beta a)}{\beta(1+\beta)^2} $$
Then using the value of $S$ can be written as:
$$S''=\frac{S(\frac{1+\beta}{1+\beta a})(I_C-I_{CO})(1+\beta a)}{\beta(1+\beta)^2}$$
Notice how the terms cancel out:
$$S''=\frac{S(\frac{\cancel{1+\beta}}{\cancel{1+\beta a}})(I_C-I_{CO})\cancel{(1+\beta a)}}{\beta(1+\beta)^{\cancel{2}}}$$
$$S''=\frac{S(I_C-I_{CO})}{\beta(1+\beta)}$$
$$\therefore S''=\frac1{\beta(1+\beta)}S(I_C-I_{CO})$$

Comment: @Soumee please check for arithmetic and definition errors

Comment: I don't think there's an error in your solution. It seems correct.

Comment: But I don't see it being the same with your value for $S''$, there could be something

Comment: Might I ask on what topic/problem in physics this is?

Comment: This is about Bipolar Junction Transistors. The topic is 'stability factors of a voltage divider bias circuit.' I have found out $S$ and $S'$. This is the calculation for $S''=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial\beta}$ , provided $V_{BE}$ and $I_{CO}$ are constant.